# how to compare a lot of values in a hash with each other

Tags: ruby

i have a hash which looks like the one below. I want to compare all "BEFORE" values with their corresponding "AFTER" values. When all are identical, i execute some code.. Currently iam doing it with an IF statement, which is pretty ugly. How would i do that usually?

```
 hash = {
  "id_BEFORE"=>10825,
  "name_BEFORE"=>"management",
  "prefix_BEFORE"=>"10.70.230.0/24",
  "created_at_BEFORE"=>Thu, 10 Oct 2019 12:07:23 UTC +00:00,
  "updated_at_BEFORE"=>Thu, 10 Oct 2019 12:07:23 UTC +00:00,
  "snapshot_id_BEFORE"=>18,
  :entry1_ipnexthop_BEFORE=>"10.70.230.72",
  :entry1_ifname_BEFORE=>"mgmt0",
  :entry1_pref_BEFORE=>0,
  :entry1_metric_BEFORE=>0,
  :entry1_clientname_BEFORE=>"direct",
  :entry1_route_type_BEFORE=>"",
  "id_AFTER"=>10828,
  "name_AFTER"=>"management",
  "prefix_AFTER"=>"10.70.230.0/24",
  "created_at_AFTER"=>Thu, 10 Oct 2019 12:07:35 UTC +00:00,
  "updated_at_AFTER"=>Thu, 10 Oct 2019 12:07:35 UTC +00:00,
  "snapshot_id_AFTER"=>19,
  :entry1_ipnexthop_AFTER=>"10.70.230.72",
  :entry1_ifname_AFTER=>"mgmt0",
  :entry1_pref_AFTER=>0,
  :entry1_metric_AFTER=>0,
  :entry1_clientname_AFTER=>"direct",
  :entry1_route_type_AFTER=>""
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
diff = hash.select do |k, v|
  next unless k.to_s.include?('AFTER')

  attr = k.to_s.split('AFTER').first
  v != (hash["#{attr}BEFORE"] || hash["#{attr}BEFORE".to_sym])
end

p diff
#=> { "id_AFTER" => 10828, "created_at_AFTER" => "Thu, 10 Oct 2019 12:07:35 UTC +00:00","updated_at_AFTER" => "Thu, 10 Oct 2019 12:07:35 UTC +00:00", "snapshot_id_AFTER" => 19 }

# You can use it in IF statement
do_something if diff.empty?
```

Comment: Good answer. Initially I thought `hash = { "id_BEFORE"=>10828, "id_AFTER"=>10828, "cat_AFTER="meow" }` would be a problem, but the question doesn't require the values of all `"AFTER"` keys to equal the values of all `"BEFORE"` keys.  Note that a return value of `true` or `false` is all that is asked for (`diff.empty?`, but more direct to use `hash.any?` or `hash.all?`.

Comment: I just noticed a problem. Suppose `hash = {  "a_BEFORE"=>"cat", :a_AFTER=>"cat" }`. Then `diff #=> {}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you make all of your keys strings you can do something like

```
hash.select { |k, _v| k.end_with?("BEFORE") }.all? { |k, v| v == hash["#{k.gsub("_BEFORE", "")}_AFTER"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def pairs?(h, suffix1, suffix2)
  h1 = select(h, suffix1).transform_keys do |k|
    case k
    when Symbol
      k.to_s.sub(/#{suffix1}\z/, suffix2).to_sym
    else # String
      k.sub(/#{suffix1}\z/, suffix2)
    end
  end
  h2 = select(h, suffix2)
  h1.all? { |k,v| h2[k] == v }
end

def select(h, suffix)
  h.select { |k,_| k.to_s.end_with?(suffix) }
end
```

**Examples**

```
h = {
  "id_BEFORE"=>10825,
  "id_AFTER" =>10828,
  :entry1_ipnexthop_BEFORE => "10.70.230.72",
  :entry1_ipnexthop_AFTER  => "10.70.230.72",
  "name_BEFORE"            => "management",
  "name_AFTER"             => "management",
  "prefix_BEFORE"          => "10.70.230.0/24",
  "prefix_AFTER"           => "10.70.230.0/24",
  "1_more_AFTER"           => "fake value" 
}
```

```
pairs?(h, "_BEFORE", "_AFTER")
  #=> false
```

```
pairs?(h.merge("id_AFTER"=>10825), "_BEFORE", "_AFTER")
  #=> true
```

**Explanation**

Note that [Hash#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-select) (unlike [Enumerable#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)) returns a hash.

The steps are as follows for `h` as defined in the examples.

```
suffix1 = "_BEFORE"
suffix2 = "_AFTER"

g = select(h, suffix1)
  #=> {"id_BEFORE"=>10825, :entry1_ipnexthop_BEFORE=>"10.70.230.72",
  #    "name_BEFORE"=>"management", "prefix_BEFORE"=>"10.70.230.0/24"} 
h1 = g.transform_keys do |k|
  case k
  when Symbol
    k.to_s.sub(/#{suffix1}\z/, suffix2).to_sym
  else # String
    k.sub(/#{suffix1}\z/, suffix2)
  end
end
  #=> {"id_AFTER"=>10825, :entry1_ipnexthop_AFTER=>"10.70.230.72",
  #    "name_AFTER"=>"management", "prefix_AFTER"=>"10.70.230.0/24"} 
h2 = select(h, suffix2)
  #=> {"id_AFTER"=>10828, :entry1_ipnexthop_AFTER=>"10.70.230.72",
  #    "name_AFTER"=>"management", "prefix_AFTER"=>"10.70.230.0/24",
  #     "1_more_AFTER"=>"fake value"} 
h1.all? { |k,v| h2[k] == v }
  #=> false
```

[Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) returns `false` because `h2[k] == v #=> false` when `k #=> "id_AFTER` (so `h2[k] #=> 10828`) and `v #=> 10825`.

If we change the value of `h["id_AFTER"]` to `10825` `true` is returned:

```
h2 = select(h.merge("id_AFTER"=>10825), suffix2)
  #=> {"id_AFTER"=>10825, :entry1_ipnexthop_AFTER=>"10.70.230.72",
  #    "name_AFTER"=>"management", "prefix_AFTER"=>"10.70.230.0/24",
  #    "1_more_AFTER"=>"fake value"} 
h1.all? { |k,v| h2[k] == v }
  #=> true     h1.all? { |k,v| h2[k] == v }
```

Comment: Cary, why can't you just match the keys containing "BEFORE" with the keys containing "AFTER", and see if the two subsets are equal? Am I missing something?

Comment: @BobRodes, the OP states, "I want to compare all "BEFORE" values with their corresponding "AFTER" values." By "values" I assume that, for each key `kb` whose name ends with `"_BEFORE"`, there is a key `ka` which has the same name except it ends with `"AFTER"`, and `h[ka] == h[kb] #=> true`. Also, notice that, in my example, there is no key `"1_more_BEFORE"` to match the key `"1_more_AFTER"`.  I did that to make that point that the question does not preclude the possibility that there may be `"AFTER"` keys without corresponding `"BEFORE"` keys.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't see why you're going to so much trouble. I don't mean to be critical, because I'm probably missing something. But, why can't you simply select all the keys that have a regex match to `/BEFORE/`, grab the values, then do the same with all the keys that match `/AFTER/`, and compare the resulting two sets of values to see whether they are the same?

Comment: @BobRodes, The OP wishes to, "...to compare all "BEFORE" values with their *corresponding* "AFTER" values", to determine if they are all equal.  Suppose `h = {  'a_BEFORE'=>1, 'b_BEFORE'=>2, 'b_AFTER'=>1, 'a_AFTER'=>2 }`. Neither of the "BEFORE" values equal their corresponding "AFTER" values, yet the arrays of their values are both `[1,2]` (in key order). To take a second example, suppose `h = {  'a_BEFORE'=>1, 'a_AFTER'=>1, 'b_AFTER'=>2 }`. All "BEFORE" values (just the one) equal their corresponding "AFTER" values, yet the arrays of their values do not: `[1]` for BEFORE, `[1,2]` for AFTER.

Comment: ...and if you compare sets of values, rather than arrays of values, you have the same problems with the examples I gave.

Comment: Derp. I am indeed missing something. I didn't think about the situation you describe, because I was taking the OP's description of his problem as comparing the set of before values with the corresponding set of after values. Maybe that's reasonable, but yours is certainly the safer interpretation! I'll edit my answer. Thanks Cary.

Answer (score 0):

This will compare all of the values whose keys contain the string "BEFORE" with all the values whose keys contain the string "AFTER", and return `true` if the values are the same and `false` if they are not:

```
h.select { |k, _| k =~ /BEFORE/ }.values == h.select { |k, _| k =~ /AFTER/ }.values
```

I think that's what you are looking for? You would have to do some extra things if your values aren't guaranteed to be in the same order. If they aren't, then first map them all to strings and then sort them. (If you don't map them all to strings, you'll run into trouble if you try to compare an integer to a string with `#sort`.) For example: `h.select { |k, _| k =~ /BEFORE/ }.values.map(&:to_s).sort`.

To plug it into your code:

```
if h.select { |k, _| k =~ /BEFORE/ }.values == h.select { |k, _| k =~ /AFTER/ }.values
  # Execute the code you want to execute
end
```

You could also break it into methods. It's probably easier to read that way:

```
def values_are_equal(h)
  h.select { |k, _| k =~ /BEFORE/ }.values == h.select { |k, _| k =~ /AFTER/ }.values
end

def execute_some_code
  # execute your code
end

execute_some_code if values_are_equal(h)
```

Edit: As Cary has explained, this won't work if values of two keys are transposed. For example, if your hash included these values:

```
:entry1_pref_BEFORE=>1
:entry1_metric_BEFORE=>0    
:entry1_pref_AFTER=>0
:entry1_metric_AFTER=>1
```

they would evaluate as the same values in the `BEFORE` and `AFTER` keys. If that can happen, you can't use the method I've described, and you can use Cary's.

Comment: “..first map them all to strings..” can be a problem if you have, say, `{ ‘a_BEFORE’=>1, :a_BEFORE=>2, ‘b_AFTER’=>2, :b_AFTER=>1 }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, that would be a problem if it comes up. In some problem domains, you'd certainly have to allow for it. But a "hash that looks like the one below" doesn't have the problem. I suppose the question then is, will it? Perhaps a robust solution would have to address the possibility.